# Finitely presentable groups are residually finite if and only if they are universally pseudofinite

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, model-theory

Suppose $G$ is finitely presentable. Then residual finiteness of $G$ is equivalent to $G$ satisfying the universal theory of finite groups (equivalently, to every existential statement true in $G$ being true in a finite group).

This is basically because residual finiteness allows us to push any existential statements true in $G$ into a finite group, and conversely, non-triviality of an element is an existential statement about the generators.

The details of the proof are a bit cumbersome, though, and it seems like the sort of result that ought to be known, so I would appreciate a reference to cite.

Comment: I think this is proved in Malcev's book *"Algebraic systems"* (written in the 60s) and not specific to groups. Then for groups, it's more or less by Stëpin in the 80s, and then by Vershik and Gordon in the 90s, who coined the terminology "LEF" (locally extended finite) for those groups.

Comment: @YCor: You're absolutely right, nothing about this is specific to groups. I'll check out Malcev's book.

Comment: @YCor: I checked the book. I've found that he writes "finitely approximable" for "residually finite", and searched the book for all occurences of "finitely approximable", but none of the theorems I've found seem to be relevant. Is the relevant work of Stëpin, Verskik and Gordon available in English?

Comment: What the Malcev book contains is the notion of being "locally embeddable" in a class (p.137). Here you consider the class of groups that are locally embeddable into the class of finite groups (in this sense). Theorem 2 p164 says in particular that a group is locally embeddable into finite groups iff it's embeddable into an ultraproduct of finite groups.

Comment: An ultraproduct is a particular case of filtering inductive limits. A general fact (actually not specific to groups) is that a group $G$ is fp iff $\mathrm{Hom}(G,-)$ commutes with filtering inductive limits [see the Adamek Rosicky book for a reference for this].  Given this, one deduces immediately that every f.p. subgroup of an ultraproduct of finite groups is residually finite.

Comment: Also: **Stëpin, A. M.**
Approximability of groups and group actions. (English. Russian original) Zbl 0554.28019
Russ. Math. Surv. 38, No. 6, 131-132 (1983); translation from Usp. Mat. Nauk 38, No. 6 (234), 123-124 (1983); **Vershik, A. M.; Gordon, E. I.**
Groups that are locally embeddable in the class of finite groups. (English. Russian original) Zbl 0898.20016
St. Petersbg. Math. J. 9, No. 1, 49-67 (1998); translation from Algebra Anal. 9, No. 1, 71-97 (1997).

Comment: @YCor: Thanks. The reference to Malcev is a bit convoluted for my taste (I'd rather put down the proof, which is pretty easy and elementary, than explain all that), but the Vershik-Gordon reference is okay (I haven't found the translated version online, but the summary on Zentralblatt already contains this, and it's not that important, so that's good enough for me).